# Removing Parenthesis when linked at beginning and end of string xslt

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I am using XSLT to remove parenthesis from labels but only when they are at the beginning and end, and only if linked.

For example

(label (1)) becomes label (1)

but

(label) (1) remains (label) (1)

---

**Edit for specifity**

More examples:

(1) becomes 1

(This is)(a (label)) remains (This is)(a (label))

(This (is) (a label)) becomes This (is) (a label)

with whatever variation in between

---

I thought I had a solution by testing characters in turn and keeping a counter to track if they were linked, but I am missing something still. Any assistance is appreciated.

Here is my current code:

```
    <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="2.0">
<xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml" doctype-system="\\ukfs11\Bks_RAPS\XML\DTDs\TFB\TFB.dtd"/>
<xsl:param name="labelstack"/>
<xsl:param name="labeltest"/>


<xsl:template match="//label[matches(.,'^\(.*\)$')]">
    <xsl:param name="labelstack" select="substring(., 1, string-length(.) - 1)"/>
    <xsl:param name="labelcounter"/>
    <xsl:call-template name="loop1">
        <xsl:with-param name="labelstack" select="$labelstack"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="labelcounter" select="0"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template name="loop1">
    <xsl:param name="labeltest" select="substring($labelstack, 1,1)"/>
    <xsl:param name="labelstack" select="substring($labelstack, 2)"/>
    <xsl:param name="labelcounter"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="string-length($labeltest) = 0">
         <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:value-of select="substring(., 2, string-length(.) - 1)"/>
         </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:when>

        <xsl:when test="$labeltest = '('">
            <xsl:variable name="labelcounter" select="$labelcounter + 1"/>
            <xsl:choose>

                <xsl:when test="$labelcounter != 0">
                    <xsl:call-template name="loop1">
                        <xsl:with-param name="labelcounter" select="$labelcounter"/>
                        <xsl:with-param name="labelstack" select="$labelstack"/>
                    </xsl:call-template>
                </xsl:when>

                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:copy>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
                    </xsl:copy>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:when>

        <xsl:when test="$labeltest = ')'">
            <xsl:variable name="labelcounter" select="$labelcounter - 1"/>
            <xsl:choose>

                <xsl:when test="$labelcounter != 0">
                    <xsl:call-template name="loop1">
                        <xsl:with-param name="labelcounter" select="$labelcounter"/>
                        <xsl:with-param name="labelstack" select="$labelstack"/>
                    </xsl:call-template>
                </xsl:when>

                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:copy>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
                    </xsl:copy>
                </xsl:otherwise>

            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:call-template name="loop1">
                        <xsl:with-param name="labelcounter" select="$labelcounter"/>
                        <xsl:with-param name="labelstack" select="$labelstack"/>
                    </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
<xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The stylesheet

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:mf="http://example.com/mf"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs mf"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:function name="mf:nested-characters" as="xs:boolean">
        <xsl:param name="input" as="xs:string"/>
        <xsl:param name="pair" as="xs:string*"/>
        <xsl:sequence select="mf:match-pairs(string-to-codepoints($input), string-to-codepoints($pair[1]), string-to-codepoints($pair[2]), 0)"/>
    </xsl:function>

    <xsl:function name="mf:match-pairs" as="xs:boolean">
        <xsl:param name="input" as="xs:integer*"/>
        <xsl:param name="open" as="xs:integer"/>
        <xsl:param name="close" as="xs:integer"/>
        <xsl:param name="count" as="xs:integer"/>
        <xsl:sequence select="
            if (not(exists($input)))
            then $count eq 0
            else if ($input[1] eq $open)
                 then mf:match-pairs(subsequence($input, 2), $open, $close, $count + 1)
                 else if ($input[1] eq $close)
                       then (if ($count eq 1 and exists($input[2]))
                             then false()
                             else mf:match-pairs(subsequence($input, 2), $open, $close, $count - 1))
                       else mf:match-pairs(subsequence($input, 2), $open, $close, $count)"/>
    </xsl:function>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* , node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="label[matches(., '^\(.*\)$')][mf:nested-characters(., ('(', ')'))]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:value-of select="replace(., '^\(|\)$', '')"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

transforms

```
<root>
    <label>(label (1))</label>
    <label>(label) (1)</label>
    <label>(1)</label>
    <label>(This is)(a (label))</label>
    <label>(This (is) (a label))</label>
</root>
```

into

```
<root>
    <label>label (1)</label>
    <label>(label) (1)</label>
    <label>1</label>
    <label>(This is)(a (label))</label>
    <label>This (is) (a label)</label>
</root>
```

Comment: Nor do I, I have 10,000 eBooks to transform, so I assume the most complex input, I would like it to handle as many layers of parentheses as possible, hence my counter solution which should in theory handle as much as I throw at it.

The idea is that every "(" it encounters increases the counter by 1, every ")" it encounters it reduces it by 1. If the string does not hit 0 by the time it gets to just before the last character, then I remove the parentheses. In this way it can go as deep and as complicated as it wants and it should still work.

Comment: @DavidBrowne, I have edited the code sample and tried to implement the check into a function which processes each (codepoint of each) character.

Comment: I have tested your code this morning on 50 ebooks and its doing exactly what I needed it to. Thank you for your time.